# XSLT inject HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I have the following XML:

```
<person>
      <name>John</name>
      <htmlDescription>A <strong>very</strong> <b><i>nice</i></b> person </htmlDescription>
</person>
```

I would somehow like to use this XML in XSLT transform to produce HTML such as

A **very** ***nice*** person

is this possible using XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you transform it to HTML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
                xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

<xsl:output method='html'/>

<xsl:template match='person'>
    <td>
        <xsl:copy-of select='htmlDescription/node()'/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you transform it to XHTML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
                xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

<xsl:output method='xml'/>

<xsl:template match='htmlDescription//text()'>
    <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='htmlDescription//*'>
    <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'>
        <xsl:copy-of select='@*'/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='node()'/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='person'>
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='htmlDescription/node()'/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. This example works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="person" >
    <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:copy-of select="htmlDescription/*"  />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect "copy-of" was the key. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VoodooRider: `htmlDescription/*` only matches elements inside of `<htmlDescription>` but not textnodes (i.e. `A ` and ` person ` aren't copied). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="htmlDescription"/>
    </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Problem is that xlst tranformer escapes some chars such as "<" and finally in my html output I get:

<td>
     A <strong>very</strong> <b>nice</b> person
</td>

insted of A **very** **nice** person

Comment: that output is correct HTML, maybe your webbrowser does not interpret the page as HTML though, but as XML. Try adding `<xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>` to your XSLT script (pretty much at the beginning). If it doesnt, there might be additional things to do depending on your XSLT Transformer and the environment it is used in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="htmlDescription"/>
        </td> 
    </tr>  
</xsl:template>
```